# Can't install elementary os 5.0 juno - kernel panic using live usb or dvd boot

Tags: boot, kernel, dvd

I am trying to install elementary os 5.0 juno from an usb and that didn't work.

i have used differents USBs and Rufus and Unetbooting and nothing works :,v
With a DVD is the same. Actually i have installed Win 10.

This is the message i get after i press "Try elementary.." or "Install elementary.."

[image: Kernel panic]

I'm new in linux so i don't know about this os or what to do :,,v

I have a intel core 2 duo
4 GB of ram.

Previously i used elementary os loki, and it worked perfectly but now i can't install juno :,v

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, my laptop just restart seconds after loading..

[I reported my issue here, no answer yet](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16444/cant-boot-on-loki-system-restart)